# Fuzzy match only if exact match doesn’t exist

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, agrep

I’m trying to write a function to get album data from Spotify’s API for a data frame of albums and artists. Because there are some misspellings in the dataset, I need to use a fuzzy matching function (like `agrepl`).

However, some artists, like Absu, have albums that are, by `agrepl`'s standards, the same. For example, Absu has an album named “Absu” and another named “Abzu”. I only want the data for 1 of them, but I’ll end up with data for both. I know that you can change `max.distance` in `agrepl`, but I need it set fairly low to account for greater misspellings.

Is there a pre-built function or an easy way to tell R

if there is an exact match of `album_name` with `mydata[["Album"]]` filter and move on
else: try and find a close match to filter?

Here’s something I’ve tried, but doesn’t work:

```r
get_album_data <- function(x) {

  get_artist_audio_features(mydata$Artist[x], return_closest_artist = TRUE) %>% 
    ifelse(album_name %in% mydata$Album[x],
           filter(mydata$Album[x] == album_name,
           filter(agrepl(mydata$Album[x], album_name, ignore.case = TRUE))))

}
```

This is what my code looks like without trying anything special

```r
library(dplyr)
library(spotifyr)
library(purrr)

# from Spotify's developer page
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = "xxx")
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxx")
access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()

Artist <- c("Spiritualized", "Fleet Foxes", "The Avalanches", "Absu")
Album <- c("Sweet Heart, Sweet Light", "Helplessness Blues", "Wildflower", "Abzu")

mydata <- data_frame(Artist, Album)

get_album_data <- function(x) {
  get_artist_audio_features(mydata[["Artist"]][x], return_closest_artist = TRUE) %>% 
    filter(agrepl(mydata[["Album"]][x], album_name, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(mydata[["Artist"]][x])
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Make a list of all the album names, all the possible misspellings (most obvious), then create a ternary tree to find them.

Comment: Can you provide few rows of data and the expected output ? That'll address the problem on target I think.

Comment: @sln Thanks for the response. `mydata` here is just an example of my actual data. I have a dataframe of over 1000 albums, so I can't do that.

Comment: Do you know all of the albumn names ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat It's kind of hard to show the expected output here, but, with the artist "Absu" in particular, he has albums titled "Abzu" and "Absu". In `mydata` I only want "Abzu". However, with my use of `agrepl` I get the data for both "Abzu" and "Absu" since they're -- according to my function -- the same. Is that enough, or do you want me to post actual output?

Comment: @sln Yes, but there are some misspellings in them, so I need `agrepl`. I just want my function to move on if it finds a perfect match, and, if not, find the next closest match, if that makes any sense

Comment: How perfect does it need to be.  If close is good enough I would just do a `dplyr::inner_join`/ `anti_join` to separate out the exact matches and then run your function on the remainder. The `stringdist` package has more tunable options for matching than `agrep`.

Comment: Just use a Levenshtein distance and return a match if the distance is small and there are no ties.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I guess I really just need to return only the closest match. The issue is, with `agrepl` all matches that are within a certain distance are returned. Any easy ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can first filter out those albums that have exact match.

```
artist_with_exact_matches = mydata$Artist[which(mydata$Artist %in% mydata$Album), ]
mydata_fuzzy_match = mydata[-which(mydata$Artist %in% artist_with_exact_matches), ]
```

Then use fuzzy match to find Artist and Album matches for the rest.